# How to show MPVideoPlayer in landscape mode and all other views in portrait?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Ive seen similar question asked already so apologies if there were a correct answer I missed. 
My app has to be in portrait mode all the time except when it shows media player which has to be in landscape full screen mode.

Here is how its done:

AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation HCAAppDelegate

+(void) landscapeLock {
    HCAAppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.screenIsLandscapeOnly= true;
    appDelegate.screenIsPortraitOnly = false;
}

+(void) portraitLock 
{
    HCAAppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.screenIsPortraitOnly = true;
    appDelegate.screenIsLandscapeOnly = false;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
...
  [HCAAppDelegate portraitLock];
}


- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    if (self.screenIsPortraitOnly) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    } else if (self.screenIsLandscapeOnly) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    } else {
        if(self.window.rootViewController) {
            UIViewController *presentedViewController = [[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
            orientations = [presentedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
        }
        return orientations;
    }
}
```

Media player is created as

```
-(void) _initPlayer
{
    [HCAAppDelegate landscapeLock];

    _moviePlayer = [[HCAMoviePlayerController alloc]init];
    [_moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];

    _moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
    [_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}
```

and dismissed as

```
- (void) _finishPlay
{
...
    [_moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    [HCAAppDelegate portraitLock];
}
```

When player is initialized it goes to landscape, but when  its dismissed it still remains in the landscape mode , why the portraitLock method did not work ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After looking more into this issue I understood where the bug is. Will post the answer here to close the case and provide a working example of subj.
Adding mediaPlayer view to the existing view controller
    [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
works but after removing it 
    [_moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
the portraitLock does not affect self.view

The working way is to create a new controller and present / dismiss it:

here is the code: 
Presenting the view for FullScreen playback. Note that height/width is switched in the 
line _moviePlayer.view setFrame:

```
UIViewController *movieVC = (UIViewController*) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MoviePlayer"];

movieVC.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                        0,
                                                        [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width,
                                                        [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height)];

[HCAAppDelegate landscapeLock];

[_moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                       0,
                                       movieVC.view.frame.size.height,
                                       movieVC.view.frame.size.width)];

[movieVC.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:movieVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Dismissing the view:

```
[_moviePlayer stop];
[HCAAppDelegate portraitLock];
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```